# Receiving a bunch of cannot redeclare blocked scope variable for library @types files

Tags: typescript, requirejs, amd, tsconfig

I am receiving a bunch of TS errors from leaflet and leaflet-editable @types I have included in my project, all repeating the same error but just referencing different lines in the type definition files:

> TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'L'.

My project is being built into AMD format and loaded with requireJS.

My tsconfig is as follows:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "rootDir": "../",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noImplicitThis": false,
        "noUnusedLocals": false,
        "noUnusedParameters": false,
        "pretty": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "allowUnreachableCode": false,
        "declaration": false,
        "allowJs": true,
        "module": "amd",
        "typeRoots" : ["./typings/index.d.ts", "../../node_modules/@types"],
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    },
    "include": [
        "./typings/index.d.ts",
        "./globals.d.ts",
        "./app/**/*.module.ts",
        "./app/**/*.run.ts",
        "./app/**/*.routes.ts",
        "./app/**/*.enum.ts",
        "./app/**/*.controller.ts",
        "./app/**/*.model.ts",
        "./app/**/*.directive.ts",
        "./app/**/*.component.ts",
        "./app/**/*.filter.ts",
        "./app/**/*.service.ts",
        "./app/interfaces/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "dist",
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

I am unsure what to do with this error, my application loads up fine and functions as expected in the browser.

Can anyone provide me with any clues? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'L'.

You have the type definition installed twice.

## Cause

Many things can cause this e.g. a library you use also bringing in a type definition that you *also* depend on.

## Fix

Make sure you only have one copy of each type definition you depend on

Comment: Thanks, it seems the leaflet-editable type is indeed pulling in another type for leaflet as a dependency but I already have leaflet as a top level dependency in my project. Can tsconfig be configured to ignore transitive dependencies?

Comment: `an tsconfig be configured to ignore transitive dependencies?` No. And you might find a hack but it would be weird for the next guy to figure out.

Comment: Ok well the problem I got is that the version of leaflet pulled in leaflet-editable is 0.7, but the latest version  of leaflet I am pulling in is much higher (1.3), surely I do t want to have to delete the 0.7 version manually? It will always get re-fetched on reinstallation of @types